# Are tags disabled in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, tags

I am unable to tag any item in a list or document libarary.

After some research I came to know that the Microsoft has retired the tags and notes features in SharePoint Online. This  **[article](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/SharePoint-Online-Tags--Notes-feature-retired-77851bd5-6d5e-42fe-9bf6-d7c17eeb771f?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN)** which states this.

Could you please let me know why this feature is retired in SharePoint Online?

Comment: A hint to any alternative solution wouldn't hurt that post I think, but perhaps Taxonomy is "taking over"?

Comment: @eirikb Thanks for the comment.Could you please provide some pointer on this/ or how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the Tags and Notes have been retired as Microsoft's recommendation is for organizations to use the Yammer enterprise social networking solution instead.